# SMTP Password with special characters - utf8 - java mail - encoding issue?

Tags: java, encoding, smtp, jakarta-mail, smtp-auth

I'm trying to send an email via java.mail SMTP. I have 2 mail accounts using the same provider and settings:

1. using a short password with no special characters
2. using a long password with special characters (* > / % !)

The first one works. The second one says `535 Authentication credentials invalid`.

I'm using java.mail 1.5.

Here's my code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.1und1.de");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("foo@example.org", "$§$&/&%§$!><>");
    }
});

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
transport.connect("smtp.1und1.de", username, password);

Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("foo@example.org"));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("bar@example.org"));
message.setSubject("subject");
message.setText("text");

transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```

Do I need to encode the password somehow?

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT:

I now tried to login via telnet. Same problem. So this isn't related to Java, but it may be some common SMTP issue.

Using the E-Mail account using Apple Mail on Mac and iPhone works without any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have non-ASCII special characters, you'll need to use [JavaMail 1.6](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release) and set the [`mail.mime.allowutf8`](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html#mail.mime.allowutf8) Session property.  And the server needs to support the SMTPUTF8 extension.

Comment: The JavaDoc says that `allowutf8` is for Mail Headers. Not for authentication. But I still tried it and now the log says that the server doesn't support SMTPUTF8.

Comment: You're right, if you just need utf-8 for authentication, you shouldn't need to set allowutf8.  What authentication mechanism is being used?